# how to use perl to generate a text file for an original reply email

Tags: perl, email

I'd like to automatically generate a text file for an original reply email, for example, like the following:

```
Subject: hello
Mime-Version: 1.0 (Mac OS X Mail 6.6 \(1510\))
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset=us-ascii
X-Apple-Base-Url: x-msg://5/
X-Universally-Unique-Identifier: f3193934-f4df-4b36-95ab-36f3171570b8
X-Apple-Mail-Remote-Attachments: YES
From: Some Person <usera@mydomain.com>
X-Apple-Windows-Friendly: 1
Date: Mon, 24 Feb 2014 14:43:11 -0800
X-Apple-Mail-Signature: SKIP_SIGNATURE
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Message-Id: <41FFDBF3-D482-45A4-A11F-CA545621B513@mydomain.com>
X-Smtp-Server: mymachine
X-Uniform-Type-Identifier: com.apple.mail-draft
To: userb@mydomain.com

<html><head></head><body style="word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-nbsp-mode: space; -webkit-line-break: after-white-space; "></body></html>
```

This is obtained from first replying to an incoming email, then in the `sent` box, I can see `show original source`.

Is there any way to automatically generate this email as a text file, or print out on to stdout?

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean. Can you not just wrap that in quotes and put `print` before it?

Comment: i meant to say generate the whole email in text, for example, how to get `X-Universally-Unique-Identifier` or `Message-Id`

Answer (score 0):

Those cryptic values assigned by SMTP/Exchnage servers, it should not be generated by client programs.

You could generate emails this way: http://learn.perl.org/examples/email.html